# JLabel not showing the complete string when using paintImmediately() method?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is a code snippet for setting text on a `JLabel`.

While setting the label using the `paintImmediately()` method it doesn't show the string properly:

```
label.setText("Processing");
label.paintImmediately(testResultLabel.getVisibleRect());
currentTestStatusLabel.paintImmediately(currentTestStatusLabel.getVisibleRect());
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to paint immediately? Why won't `revalidate` and `repaint` work in your case? Why are you passing `testResultLabel.getVisibleRect` to `label`s `paintImmediately` method? The "problem" is, you've changed the label's text, which doesn't directly change the "physical" size, you need a layout pass to run on the parent container to do that

Answer (score 0):

found the solution which works as of now :

`label.setText("<html>"+someText+"</html>");`